# Building single project for android under jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

I just set up jenkins to build android projects for me but at the moment it seems to build all my projects under the workspace. Is there a way to define which project I want jenkins to build?

Current workspace structure is as below

```
Workspace 
- project 1
- project 2
- project 3
```

In git I have it all checked under one branch. So when I check out it checks out all my projects.

I just need to know how to get jenkins to only build one of those projects. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If there is a command line way of building your projects then I will execute a shell script as a part of the build (Execute shell). This shell script can take an passed parameter which will actually stand for the project you want to build.